# Force external link preview via Facebook Graph API to large image? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to force a large image preview on external links (i.e. I have no access to a page's metadata for og:image) in Facebook posts via graph? eBay in particular seems to vary the size of image it provides at random (some image URLs end in 's-l500.jpg' and display a large preview, some in smaller versions. They host up to 's-l1600.jpg'). I understand Facebook's anti-spam reasoning, but is there a workaround for sites such as eBay that host several versions of the same image?

*I've found previous questions asking about changing image entirely, but nothing re: forcing a larger version*

The below gives a Facebook #100 error as 'picture' is now deprecated. I obviously can't take ownership of eBay.

payload = { 'message': msg,
'link': link,
'picture': url_pic,
'access_token': access_token}

'{"error":{"message":"(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params.","type":"OAuthException","code":100'

Comment: No, there is nothing you can do. Without claimed domain ownership, Facebook does not allow to change title, description and thumbnail dynamically at the time of sharing any more.